# Wait for data before rendering views in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

It's not another question about resolve I think. I would like to have simple, complex method to wait for Ajax data before rendering component in Angular 2. I will have about fifty routes, so creating resolve for each route would be pain.

Can someone share his way to wait for data before rendering view?

Comment: Not sure I got your question, but the really manual way to do it would be to set a flag such as `isReady = true` once your async call is complete and in the template wrap everything with `<div *ngIf="isReady">...</div>`. Or are you looking for something more involved?

Comment: you can use canActivate

Comment: I'm not sure I get the "I have 50 routes" part, though. If you do have 50 routes, you'll still have to do *something* 50 times. Whether you do that something inside a resolver or inside the component itself doesn't make a huge difference (as far of # of lines of code, I mean). Obviously you should avoid creating 50 unique resolvers; you could create a **single** generic resolver that examines the route, or better, some `data` param attached to the route, to decide which data it should load.

Comment: But will you agree, that creating for example one directive to handle all routes would be great. I think that someone hacked this problem in some smart way, smarter than I can imagine at this moment.

Answer (score 5):

- a resolver https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard
- `*ngIf="data"` in the view, to prevent rendering of the view while `data` is `null`
- use the safe-navigation operator `data?.prop` to prevent error in view bindings while `data` is `null`